# Update keeps coming back on MacOS

Tags: macos, catalina, software-update

I am on Catalina, latest version.
Since yesterday, I keep getting this:

[image]

I didn't know that iLife was even still a thing.

This is the update detail:

[image]

But then, when I try to install it:

[image]

and... it keeps repeating.

How can I get this over with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it (it's no longer needed as it's discontinued and was used for media creation in apps like iTunes and iPhoto):

1. Open the Terminal app (Spotlight search for 'terminal')
2. Type sudo softwareupdate --ignore iLifeSupport902
3. It will ask you for your password, enter it (you won't see it displayed on screen)
4. Close terminal and restart your Mac

It should now have disappeared.

Comment: I didn't know that command! thanks!